# pattern of I'm sorry, but

Tags: grammar

I'm sorry, but now that I have seen the plant I have some recommendations for the director about the building and machinery.

Is the above sentence correct? Why does 'that' follow 'but'?

Comment: Can you explain why you think that 'that' following 'but' is remarkable? Also, where is this sentence from?

Answer (score 0):

In this sentence "that" used as a function word

***to introduce a subordinate clause expressing a reason or cause***

Here, the sentence implies that "as the person visited the plant he has some recommendations to share with the directors about the same."

Consider the sentence—

*Now that I've tasted the food, I can give feedback to the chef.*

Comment: I buy "as I tasted the food, I can give feed back to the chef." I don't get "that I've tasted the food, I can give feed back to the chef." because I don't see any function for the word 'that' in the sentence.

Comment: @Stephen "that" introduced a subordinate clause expressing a reason or cause for his giving of feedback to the chef.

Comment: I know 'as' or 'since' can lead the antecedent clause expressing a reason or cause.

Comment: @Stephen what is your doubt??

Comment: Is the above sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: As a non-English speaker, I refer to a dictionary when I meet a sentence that I don't understand. I could not find 'that' to introduce the antecedent (adverb) clause expressing a reason or cause.

Comment: I learned English based on the English grammar. The native English speaker ignores the grammar, and understands English sentences by context. I wonder what algorithm Google Translate is using.

Comment: Stephen, it's not _that I've tasted the food_, but **now that** _I've tasted the food_. The sense is "In the present circumstances of my having seen the plant/tasted the food..."

Comment: Why is "now that?" How about "as" or "since?" I think that I'm sorry but since I've tasted... is a better expression that now that I've tasted...

Comment: There is nothing 'better' about it, it's just a slightly different way to say it. "Now that [something has happened]' is a perfectly normal and valid expression in English.

Comment: Thank you so much, Kate. It is not about 'that' but about 'now (that). I did not know that 'now' could be used as a conjunction. Now, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

According the the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/now-that?q=now%20%28that%29), "now that" is used to give an explanation of a new situation. For example,

> Now that I have some glue, I can repair your shoe.